# Access denied to shares residing on volumes other than C:

Tags: permissions, windows, windows-server-2012

I have tried this from three different virtual machines running on vSphere 5.0 with the same results. All disks are Virtual Disks as provided by ESXi (not iSCSI; not NFS). All disks (C:, E:) are formatted as NTFS.

If I create a folder on the C: and share it to Everyone:FC I can access it from a client PC as expected. It's a totally normal operation. I'm not doing anything interesting with permissions or anything. If I do the same exact thing on the E: I will get an Access Denied error when trying to access the folder.

If I browse to the server itself I can see both shares but I am blocked from accessing the share that resides on the E:. I've even tried adding a 3rd disk (F:) but I get the same result. The **only** place shares work is from C:.

The Effective Access tool even states that my user should have access. But no. I do not (neither does any other user because the permissions are Everyone:FC).

Server has all the latest patches available. No antivirus is installed. I've ever tried turning off the firewall just *in case*.

**UPDATE:** As requested. Here are some example events from the security log.

Success event on C:\OTHER share (this one works)
    A handle to an object was requested.

```
Subject:
    Security ID:     SYSTEM
    Account Name:    FILES-01$
    Account Domain:  domain
    Logon ID:        0x3E7

Object:
    Object Server:   Security
    Object Type:     File
    Object Name:     C:\OTHER
    Handle ID:       0x1248
    Resource Attributes:    -

Process Information:
    Process ID:        0x3d0
    Process Name:        C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Access Request Information:
    Transaction ID:        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    Accesses:        SYNCHRONIZE
                ReadAttributes

    Access Reasons:        SYNCHRONIZE:    Granted by    D:(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)
                ReadAttributes:    Granted by    D:(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)

    Access Mask:        0x100080
    Privileges Used for Access Check:    -
    Restricted SID Count:    0
```

Failure event on E:\TEST (opposite of working)

```
A handle to an object was requested.

Subject:
    Security ID:        domain\myusername
    Account Name:        myusername
    Account Domain:        DOMAIN
    Logon ID:        0x1D8C46

Object:
    Object Server:        WS-Management Listener
    Object Type:        Unknown
    Object Name:        Unknown
    Handle ID:        0x0
    Resource Attributes:    -

Process Information:
    Process ID:        0x2c8
    Process Name:        C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Access Request Information:
    Transaction ID:        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    Accesses:        MAX_ALLOWED

    Access Reasons:        -
    Access Mask:        0x2000000
    Privileges Used for Access Check:    -
    Restricted SID Count:    0
```

Comment: What do your security logs say when you try and access these shares?

Comment: Please see the update I made above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found confirmation from MS or VMware that this is a bug but it really looks like it is one. I don't know enough about all this to state, with confidence, what is happening but what appears to be the problem is how ESXi presents supplemental disks to the OS. The problem lies in the HotPlug feature. After disabling HotPlug on the VM I was able to successfully access shares as expected.

Credit goes to [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserver8gen/thread/179c72b2-2957-43a0-8798-472e907a6e55) that pointed me to the [solution at VMware's KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012225).